# Weyl groups sends Weyl Chamber onto another:

Tags: root-systems, weyl-group

I came across two statements while studying Weyl group of root Systems.

First one: The Weyl group say $W$ sends one Weyl Chamber onto another. If $\gamma$ is regular in a Euclidean Space $E$, we have $\sigma(C(\gamma))=C(\sigma \gamma))$, if $\sigma \in W$. Any idea for how to prove this identity and see it geometrically?

Second one: $W$ sends a base $∆$ to $\sigma(∆)$ which is again a base. Although somehow it follows from the identity $\sigma(∆(\gamma))=∆(\sigma\gamma)$ which follows from $(\sigma \gamma, \sigma \alpha)=(\gamma, \alpha)$(How?).

I don't have any clear idea of these two points. It will be great if someone can help me in these!

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but here is a solution that may help future readers.

Let $\Phi$ be the root system on the real Hilbert space $E$.

Note first that if $\sigma \in \mathcal{W}$, it preserves the inner product, i.e. $\sigma$ is an isometry. Indeed, this follows easily from the fact that $\mathcal{W}$ is generated by elementary isometries $\sigma_\alpha$ where $\sigma_\alpha$ is the reflection around the hyperplane $P_\alpha$ orthogonal to the vector $\alpha$.

(1) The Weyl chambers are defined to be the connected components of the space
$$F:=E\setminus \bigcup_{\alpha \in \Phi} P_\alpha$$
i.e. the vectors $\gamma \in E$ such that none of the inner products $(\gamma, \alpha)$ are $0$.

If $\sigma\in \mathcal{W}$, then $\sigma(F)\subseteq F$. To see this, note that if $(\gamma, \alpha)\ne 0$ for all $\alpha \in \Phi$, we have for $\alpha\in \Phi$ that
$$(\sigma(\gamma), \alpha) = (\sigma(\gamma), \sigma(\sigma^{-1}(\alpha))) = (\gamma, \sigma^{-1}(\alpha)) \ne 0$$
where we used that transformations in the Weyl group map $\Phi$ into itself (this is an axiom of root systems). We conclude that the restriction
$$\sigma: F \to F$$
is a homeomorpism. As such, it maps connected components to connected components. It follows now trivially that
$$\sigma(C(\gamma)) = C(\sigma(\gamma))$$
since $\sigma(C(\gamma))$ is a connected component of $F$ containing $\sigma(\gamma)$.

(2) If $\Delta$ is a base of $\Phi$, it is straightforward to see that $\sigma(\Delta)$ is a base. Therefore, we see that
$\sigma(\Delta(\gamma)) = \Delta(\gamma')$ for some regular $\gamma'$. This also implies $\sigma(\Phi^+(\gamma)) = \Phi^+(\gamma')$.

We must show that $\Delta(\gamma') = \Delta(\sigma(\gamma))$. To show this, it evidently suffices to show that
$$\Phi^+(\gamma') = \Phi^+(\sigma(\gamma)).$$
or equivalently
$$\Phi^+(\sigma(\gamma))=\sigma(\Phi^+(\gamma)).$$
But the latter is clear:
\begin{align}\alpha \in \Phi^+(\sigma(\gamma)) &\iff (\alpha, \sigma(\gamma)) > 0\\
&\iff (\sigma^{-1}(\alpha), \gamma) > 0\\
&\iff \sigma^{-1}(\alpha) \in \Phi^+(\gamma)\\
&\iff \alpha \in \sigma(\Phi^+(\gamma)).
\end{align}